# Añadir lista de imagenes desde assets a un Row FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

quiero hacer lo siguiente: Tengo un ListView.builder que tiene que contener un icono con un texto cada item.

Entonces, quiero agregar unas 3 imagenes(iconos) a la carpeta assets/images y pasarlas al child > children > Row del listView.builder, como lo hago?

esto mismo lo pude hacer pero con un Map de Strings, para hacer una lista con imagenes desde internet, eso es facil porque haces un mapa de strings y ya pasas el imagenes.[index].image y ya va llenando la lista dinamicamente se entiende?
Pero no se como hacer esto cuando tengo imagenes fisicas y no desde internet

Este es mi codigo, intento hacer esto pero me da error

```
class Populars {

  String name;
  String image;


  Populars(this.name, this.image);


}

List<Populars> populars = popularsData
    .map((item) => Populars(item['name'], item['image']))
    .toList();



var popularsData = [
  {
    "name": "Raja Ampat, Indonesia",
    "image": Image.asset('assets/images/icon_beach.svg')
  },

];
```

Comment: Estas tratando de guardar un widget en un String :        "image": Image.asset('assets/images/icon_beach.svg') eso no es posible, deberia ser asi: 
    "image": 'assets/images/icon_beach.svg'

Comment: o modifica tu propiedad  image a que sea del tipo Image

Comment: `popularsData` es ejemplo de lo que quieres mostrar? y las imágenes tendrán un texto o unicamente sera la imagen ?

Comment: Puedes mostrar cual es el error que te muestra ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero a realizar es cargar tus imágenes en el archivo`pubspec.yaml` tal como lo muestra en la [documentación](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) pero aquí esta un ejemplo.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/img/
```

Ya que no entiendo si quieres un `ListView` dentro de un `Row` o al revés, coloco un ejemplo de como poner un `Row` dentro de un `ListView`

```dart
    class ImagesRow extends StatelessWidget {
      final images = [
        {'image':'assets/img/1.png', 'title':'image 1'},
        {'image':'assets/img/2.png', 'title':'image 2'},
        {'image':'assets/img/3.png', 'title':'image 3'}
      ];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: images.length,
            itemBuilder: (_,i)=>Row(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  images[i]['image'],
                  width: 200,),
                Text(images[i]['title'])
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```